# Can I increment some value during database update?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, database, sql-update

Can i do something like that?

```
int somevalue=500;
string getUpSql = "UPDATE money FROM bank SET Money= @Money + somevalue WHERE UserId=@UserId";
```

I'm trying to plus some money to an account that clicks button

```
    protected void BtnWork_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();
        Guid currentUserId = (Guid)currentUser.ProviderUserKey;
string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
string getUpSql = "UPDATE money FROM bank SET Money= @Money + somevalue WHERE UserId=@UserId";
 using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {

           SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(getUpSql, myConnection);
 myConnection.Open();

 myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Money",SqlDbType.Int); 

 myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            myConnection.Close();
        }
```

Comment: If you use `@UserId`, make sure to pass it in as a parameter.  Posting the error message and definition of the Custon_MoneyWork table would help.

Comment: There is no error, it just not working:) @UserId is ok..

Comment: question is - how do i plus "somevalue"?

Comment: @RaShe - The code you posted should have given you an error. The syntax is not valid and it references a non existent parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not incrementing the value. You are setting it to `@Money + somevalue`, where `@Money`  is set to whatever the value of `SqlDbType.Int` is.

Change your SQL to this...

```
UPDATE money FROM bank SET Money = Money + @somevalue WHERE UserId = @UserId
```

...and then set the `@somevalue` and `@UserId` parameters like this...

```
int somevalue = ... ;
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("somevalue", somevalue);
TypeOfUserId UserId = ... ;
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserId", UserId);
```

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for an `UPDATE` statement to increment a column called `Money` by the amount in a parameter called `@somevalue` is

```
UPDATE  bank
SET     Money = Money + @somevalue /* Can use Money += @somevalue if 2008 */
WHERE   UserId = @UserId
```

Answer (score 1):

> `UPDATE money FROM bank SET Money= @Money + somevalue WHERE
>   UserId=@UserId`

Are you sure you want `@Money`? If you want to increment the value stored in the column Money by somevalue you need to write it like `Money = Money + @somevalue` and you have to bind somevalue as a parameter, not `Money`.

Comment: No offense, but maybe you need to learn about such stuff first instead of puzzle programming without understanding what you are actually doing. I mean come on, you already bind a parameter in your code... it's clearly you need to get the basics first.